# Smart pointer memory management across DLL boundary with object-oriented API

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, dll, unique-ptr

I think the following classes are safe to expose from a DLL as part of an API, because they contain only pure virtual members.

```
namespace myapi {
    struct Image {
        virtual int width() = 0;
        virtual int height() = 0;
        virtual unsigned char* data() = 0;
        virtual void dispose() = 0; // will `delete this` from inside the DLL
    }

    struct Camera {
        virtual Image* getFrame() = 0; // caller owns the returned object
    }
}
```

The user of the API has to remember to call `dispose()` on the pointer returned by `Camera::getFrame()`. To remove this burden from the user, I want to modify the header file to this:

```
namespace myapi {
    template<typename T>
    using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>;

    struct Image {
        virtual int width() = 0;
        virtual int height() = 0;
        virtual unsigned char* data() = 0;
        virtual ~Image(){};
    }

    struct Camera {
        unique_ptr<Image> getFrame(){
            return unique_ptr<Image>(getFrameRaw(), [](auto* i){deleteImage(i);});
        }
    private:
        virtual Image* getFrameRaw() = 0; // caller owns the returned object
    }
    extern "C" MYAPI_API void deleteImage(Image* i); // will `delete i` from inside DLL
}
```

Is it as safe as the first version? `class Camera` no longer has only pure virtual members, but the non-virtual member is right there in the header file for the EXE to inline. Does that mean what I am doing is safe?

Comment: It's the right thing to do, but I would generally try to separate the client-side function intended for inlining into a separate type (or even free functions) and not mix them into the same class.  But as long as you don't use `declspec(dllexport)` on those, you should be safe from the DLL's definition of `unique_ptr` somehow leaking in.

Comment: @BenVoigt By free function do you mean `myapi::getFrame(Camera*)`?

Comment: Yes that's a free (non-member) function.  By being outside the type, it doesn't have to be (and shouldn't be) in the header file used by the DLL itself.  It should be in a client-side public header which includes the shared header where all the pure virtual bits are.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see. I would rather wrap it then, as you also suggest.

Comment: @BenVoigt Problem is that I then have to wrap lots of members (not shown here) that didn't need wrapping.

Comment: What issue are you trying to address? Is it the risk that the client uses a different allocator than the dll? One answer might be to overload operator new and delete for the base of the struct/class, or just add ~Image, if you are only worried about the data() getting destroyed properly. With the implementation in the DLL, it won't matter what mechanism the client uses to define the object lifetime.

Comment: @GemTaylor Remove `Image::data()` and the problem is still the same: to delete `Image`-derived object on correct side of DLL, without requiring the client to free it explicitly.

Comment: Somewhat related: `delete i` won't do the right thing as `Image` doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Note that this will not compile because you need to name the Deleter when you create a `unique_ptr`. Instead, specialize the default deleter: `template<> struct std::default_delete<Image> {  operator()(Image* i) { deleteImage(i);}; };` As long as this `unique_ptr` is never passed between DLLs, you'll be okay. (Note that even classes consisting only of pure virtual methods is not necessarily safe to pass between DLLs, although in practice you'll probably get away with it.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Why will this not compile? I did test it, but may have made a typo in the question.

Comment: The `return unique_ptr<Image>(getFrameRaw(), [](auto* i){deleteImage(i);});` does not compile because the second parameter (the lambda) does not match the Deleter type (second template parameter), which is `std::default_delete<Image>`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Did you see line 3?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Thanks. But it is confusing to give a custom type the same name as a standard type. Somebody is going to try to put a `myapi::unique_ptr` in a `std::unique_ptr` without realizing it.

Comment: @Museful Yes, if Image is actually some base class, then it will have more things to destroy, of course. But if you can follow the c++ derivation model, and with destructor and operator delete members declared and implemented in the dll, the client code doesn't need to care.